# Applying style to only one div based on state change

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, state

I'm rendering 4 divs from the data i get from my backend.I'm coloring these divs according to a state change. So far i'm doing it successfully but the only problem is all 4 divs can be colored this way. I want to uncolor previous div when i color another div. How can i do this?

My code

```
textVote() {

        this.setState({

            vote_status: !this.state.vote_status

        })

    }

handleClick(id) {

        let vote_object = {
            voting_object: id,
            post_id: this.props.postId
        }
        this.props.submitvote(vote_object)
        this.textVote();

    }


render() {

        console.log("getVoteStatus", this.props.getVoteStatus)

        let {contents, submitvote, postId} = this.props

return (

        <div className="txt_vote_bar_div" style={{backgroundColor: this.state.vote_status ? '#0b97c4' : 'white'}}>
           <p className="txt_vote_choice" style={{color: this.state.vote_status ? '#FFFFFF' : '#6a6a6a'}}
               id={contents.post_poll_content_id} onClick={() => {

                     this.handleClick(contents.post_poll_content_id);

                  }}> {contents.content} </p>
            <p className="txt_tot_votes" style={{color: this.state.vote_status ? '#FFFFFF' : '#6a6a6a'}}> 56% (Votes: {contents.votes}) </p>
        </div>
   );
    };
```

How can i make it so i only color one div background and remove background color when i select another.Thanks.

Comment: What would determine which div should be coloured? I can only see one div in this example (And its not within a render function?)

Comment: @jye265 in handleClick method i'm changing a state.based on that state background coloring is happening

Comment: Are you mapping / looping this render function in any way? If yes, at which point?

Comment: Is this component used 4 times from a parent/container component?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to have multiple div, which when you click each div it will change color and at the same time other div will change back to it's default color. Am I right?

My solution would be something like this. Specifiy each component as a number.

```
handleClick = (number) =>{
  this.setState({
      vote_status: number
  })
}

render() {
  {data.map((content,index) => {
    <div
      style={{backgroundColor: this.state.vote_status === index ? '#0b97c4' : 'white'}}
      onClick={() => {this.handleClick(index)}}>
    </div>
  })}
}
```

Comment: i'm mapping only one div. The same div repeats 4 times according to backend content. If there were more than 4 contents in my backend , it would rendermore than 4 times

Comment: Can you please show us the code that is used to render this component? The logic for only selecting one div at a time (by only setting vote_status to true on one component at at time) will be done in the parent component

Comment: @CraZyDroiD I have edit my answer, you can use index number